# Powershell: search backwards from end of file

Tags: powershell, scripting

My script reads a log file once a minute and selects (and acts upon) the lines where the timestamp begins with the previous minute.

This is easy (the regex is simply "^$timestamp"), but when the log gets big it can take a while.

My thinking is the lines I want will always be near the bottom of the file, so I'd be searching far fewer lines if I started at the bottom and searched upwards, stopping when I get to the minute prior to the one I'm interested in.

My question is, how can I search from the bottom of the file instead of the top?  Can I even say "read line $length", or even "read line n" (if so I could do a sort of binary search thing to find the length of the file and work backwards from there)?

Last question: would this even be faster (I'd still like to know how to do it even if it wouldn't be faster)?

Ideally, I'd like to do this all in my own code without installing anything extra.

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

**get-content bigfile.txt -tail 10**

This words on huge files nearly instantly without any big memory usage.

I did it with a 22 GB text file in my testing.

Doing something like "get-context bigfile.txt | select -Last 10" works but it seems to have to load all of the lines (or objects in powershell) then does the select.

Comment: You need to use PowerShell 3 or higher, but if you do, this is the best answer.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. working flawlessly for me

Answer (score 5):

May I suggest just changing the regex to equal Get-Date + whatever time period you want?

For example (and this is without your log so i apologize)

```
$a = Get-Date
$hr =  $a.Hour
$min =  $a.Minute
```

Then work off those values to build out the regex to select the times you want. And if you don't already use it this website is awesome for building regex's quickly and easily http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ .

Got another fix, I think you will like this..

```
$a = get-content .\biglog.text
```

Use the length to slice the array from back to front change write host to select-string and your regex or whatever you want to do in reverse..

```
foreach($x in $a.length..0){ write-host $a[$x] }
```

Another option after the get-content cmdlet again, this option just reverse orders the array then you are reading $a from bottom to top

```
[array]::Reverse($a)
```

dc

Comment: Yeah, that's almost exactly what I've done :) (with a -1 to get the last full minute), it's just that I'm thinking at the moment it has to read all of the log until it reaches the previous minute (OK, so it only has to read up to eight characters per line, but still), which will always be at the bottom, so wouldn't it be easier to read backwards from the bottom line, thus reading far fewer lines.

Comment: If I do $a = get-content .\biglog.text will that read the whoooooooooole file into memory?  I think that would quickly use up all the memory on the server.

Comment: I assume it is much like many other programming languages and yes assigning biglog.txt will pull it into ram, however there may be some memory allocation kung-fu happening in the background. Might be good question on its own.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the last bit of the file, depending on the format, you can just do this:

```
Get-Content C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log | Select -last 10
```

This will return the last 10 lines found in the file.

Comment: Nice as well, thats 3 differnt ways to get the last logs or work back to front.

Comment: I see how that would help, but I have the same question as with @dc5553's: will calling Get-Content read the whole file into memory?  This is going to run on a production server so I can't afford to use up all the memory.

Comment: Putting Get-Content into a variable it will read it into memory, however filtering down the Get-Content command as I did it will only hold that last 10 lines of the file in memory. At least as far as I know...

Comment: Your best way to find this out is do it on your desktop, with something like ProcessExplorer so you see how much memory is consumed using each solution provided.